# JSF facelets - How do I put a template <ui:insert> tag into a panel header value?

Tags: templates, jsf, primefaces, facelets

For example this panel:

```
<p:panel header="Template insert field here...">
</p:panel>
```

This doesnt work:

```
<p:panel header="<ui:insert name="content">Content here</ui:insert>">
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<f:facet>` instead.

```html
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content here</ui:insert>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: You make it look so easy ;) Thx